# Рефлексия. Создать экземпляр внутреннего класса имеющего конструктор с параметром

Tags: java, рефлексия

День добрый.
Имеется экземпляр некоторого внутреннего класса имеющего конструктор с *параметром*.
Тоесть:

```
class A{
...
  class B{
    B(int i){
    }
  }
...
  class C{
    C(int i){
    }
  }
...
}
```

Как используя рефлексию создать ещё один экземпляр этого класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class<?> enclosingClass = Class.forName("A");
Object enclosingInstance = enclosingClass.newInstance();

Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("A$B");
Constructor<?> ctor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(enclosingClass, int.class);

Object innerInstance = ctor.newInstance(enclosingInstance, 42);
```